# select all dates that are due in 7 days

Tags: mysql

I have the following query (which does not work):

```
SELECT user_id FROM due_dates WHERE due_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

I want to select all the user_id's where the due_date is due in exactly 1 week.

What my script does?

It sends an e-mail like "your account is due in 7 days".

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the more natural shorthand.

If `due_date` is type `DATE`:

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM due_dates
 WHERE due_date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

If `due_date` is another temporal (`DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`):

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM due_dates
 WHERE due_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
   AND due_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This allows the optimiser to use an available index on `due_date`, and prevents any `23:59:59` messiness when using the inclusive `BETWEEN`.

**N.B.** This will effectively convert a temporal to a date before doing a comparison. A row with a due_date of `2000-01-08 10:00:00` will be considered 7 days after a `NOW()` of `2000-01-01 xx:xx:xx` and returned.

In @BerndBuffen's answer, if `NOW()` returns `2000-01-01 09:00:00`, the row will be filtered out, and if `NOW()` returns `2000-01-02 09:00:00`, the row will be returned.

It's a subtle but important difference.

Answer (score 1):

use this query. if you use **BETWEEN** MySQL can use a index on due_date else it is a FULL TABLE SCAN.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM due_dates
WHERE due_date BETWEEN 
    timestamp(date (now() -interval 1 week))
AND
    timestamp(date(now() - interval 1 week + interval 1 day));
```

**SAMPLE**

```
mysql> select * from due_dates;
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | due_date            |
+---------+---------------------+
|      13 | 2015-10-16 01:00:00 |
|      14 | 2015-10-16 05:00:00 |
|      15 | 2015-10-17 04:00:00 |
|      16 | 2015-10-17 05:00:00 |
|      17 | 2015-10-18 01:00:00 |
|      18 | 2015-10-19 01:00:00 |
|      19 | 2015-11-16 01:00:00 |
|      20 | 2015-11-16 05:00:00 |
|      21 | 2015-11-17 04:00:00 |
|      22 | 2015-11-17 05:00:00 |
|      23 | 2015-11-18 01:00:00 |
|      24 | 2015-11-19 01:00:00 |
|       7 | 2016-10-16 01:00:00 |
|       8 | 2016-10-16 05:00:00 |
|       9 | 2016-10-17 04:00:00 |
|      10 | 2016-10-17 05:00:00 |
|      11 | 2016-10-18 01:00:00 |
|      12 | 2016-10-19 01:00:00 |
|       1 | 2016-11-16 01:00:00 |
|       2 | 2016-11-16 05:00:00 |
|       3 | 2016-11-17 04:00:00 |
|       4 | 2016-11-17 05:00:00 |
|       5 | 2016-11-18 01:00:00 |
|       6 | 2016-11-19 01:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
24 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT user_id
    -> FROM due_dates
    -> WHERE due_date BETWEEN
    -> timestamp(date (now() -interval 1 week))
    -> AND
    -> timestamp(date(now() - interval 1 week + interval 1 day));
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       3 |
|       4 |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT user_id FROM due_dates WHERE due_date BETWEEN  timestamp(date (now() -interval 1 week)) AND timestamp(date(now() - interval 1 week + interval 1 day));
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | due_dates | NULL       | range | due_date      | due_date | 5       | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Pretty sure it show be now + interval 1 week, not minus.. OP wants accounts due 7 days in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM due_dates
WHERE DATE(due_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
-- if due_date is already DATE type then the following should work:
-- WHERE due_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```